# Time validation with RegularExpression

Tags: regex, validation, time

I'm new of the Objective-C's code programming.... and is the first time that I post a question over Stackoverflow.

Somebody can say me why this piece of code don't works?
I've tested the Regular Expression on the test web site and work fine, but in Xcode don't works.... I need to validate a time in this format (HH:MM).

Thanks all...

(the code)

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *expression = [[NSString alloc] init];
    if (textField == self.TB_orarioPartenza)
    {

       expression = @"^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$";
    }
    if (textField == self.TB_numGiri) {
        expression = @"^d{2}";
    }

    NSString *newString =[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression 
                                                                           options:0 
                                                                             error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];         
    if (numberOfMatches == 0) return NO;        

    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **h:mm** format (for example *"9:35"*) use use regex:

`^(?:0?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

For **hh:mm** format (for example *"09:35"*) use use regex:

`^(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$`

Comment: don't works.... :(  
In the sense that works like RegEx code, but not in the Xcode syntax!!!

Comment: @Blasco73 - You probably do not check the string for validation, but trying to find matches in complex string. For such kind of task for **hh:mm** format use `(?<!\d)((?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])(?!\d)` with optional `?` behind first `0` for **h:mm** format.

Comment: No... don't go!! The effect that I want is to stop insert if you try to insert a wrong character... 
But I change my goal and make a validation to all string when text box lost focus. So your first solutions works fine.
Thanks however you was precious